# Android Studio app doesn't install on emulator after androidx migration

Tags: android, android-studio, migration, androidx

my dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

I had an app which worked fine on Android Pie and it used older support libraries. However, I decided to migrate it to AndroidX to be able to support the latest version. I didn't change any logical code, just allowed the Studio(3.5) to change the imports. Now when I test it it crashes on Pie (even when i change the target sdk and/or compilation sdk to 28) and on emulator with Android 10 it works fine. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that;

- Your com.android.tools.build:gradle version is more that 3.2.0
- Your gradle.properties file has android.useAndroidX = true
- Your Android studio version is higher than 3.2 your
  TargetSDK verion and compliedSDK version is 28 or greater.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Studio 3.5 and I checked all, all the requirements are met, however, it still crashes on Pie and lower...